# Rails Post multipart form with JSON and file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, multipartform-data

I am making a POST request from my Ruby on Rails controller to an API. The API needs to receive a multipart form where one part is JSON and the other part is a file.

Here's my best stab at it so far:

```
Api::Document.post("document_versions",
                        user_id: params[:user_id].to_i, 
                        client_token: params[:client_token], 
                        file_name: params[:file_name], 
                        doc_name: params[:doc_name],
                        doc_type_id: params[:doc_type_id].to_i,
                        file: params[:upload].tempfile,
                        "Content-type" => "multipart/form-data; boundary= SomethingToSeparateParts")
```

On the API side, it receives

```
{"method":"POST","auth_token":"12345","timestamp":"2015-05-26T20:18:16Z","status_code":500,"request_url":"/v1/document_versions","duration":"3.902005ms","user_agent":"Faraday v0.9.0","request_body":"{\"user_id\":138,\"client_token\":\"12345\",\"file_name\":\"benTest.png\",\"doc_name\":\"BENTEST\",\"doc_type_id\":1,\"file\":[\"�PNG\\r\\n\",\"\\u001A\\n\",\"\\u00
```

...

```
0000\\u0000IEND�B`�\"],\"Content-type\":\"multipart/form-data; boundary= SomethingToSeparateParts\"}"}
```

So I think I have it coming as multipart/form-data, but it only has one part -- the JSON containing all attributes, including the file. I would like the JSON to contain everything BUT the file, and the file to be separated to another part of the multipart, separated by the boundary. How can I do this?

Comment: What is `Api::Document` in this case?

Comment: not sure exactly WHAT it is, but it allows me to make a POST that my Api can read. I'm a Rails beginner, still not sure how all the pieces fit together.

Comment: I'd dig some more and see where that comes from. It's not clear what options that method accepts from your example.

Comment: my Document model has `include Her::Model`. Perhaps the post is a part of that?

Comment: This is something in the `Api` namespace, so I'd try and track that down. One way to do it: `raise Api::Document.method(:post).source_location.inspect`

Comment: OK, I did that and now I'm looking at the file it referenced (It's the Her Model), but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Document is not in that file, but the Document model inherits from it, if I'm understanding the structure correctly.

Comment: You're going to have to look around in there some more. The `source_location` method gives you an idea of where to start poking about.